# Annotation based Scala Json validation for Case Class

Tags: json, scala, validation, playframework

I am looking for suggestion where we can use annotations to setup validation for json in Play **2.6.x** with Scala. 
For Ex.

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Integer)
```

Here `age` and `name` should be not null and name should not be empty. If we are receiving json

```
{name : "", age : 10}
```

I should be able to reply with message `Invalid name` or `Invalid Age` if age is incorrect.

I am looking for below mentioned solution

```
case class Person(@NotEmpty(message = "Invalid Name")name: String, @NotNull(message = "Invalid Age")age: Integer)
```

Comment: Play uses PlayJson for Json handling. I don't think that PlayJson supports things like annotations. Where did you read about annotations in PlayJson ?

Comment: Play JSON is using macros to generate handlers, according types, meaning that not `Option`al fields cannot be null by definition. Please read documentation first.

Comment: Try this https://www.jdoodle.com/a/kbX, I haven't tested this with JSON, but give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sane validation library for Scala: https://github.com/wix/accord